# Distance from a point to a weird set

Tags: geometry

Fix some $\delta \gt 0$.
Consider a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $||2x|| \lt \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{n}}$.
Define $y = -x$.
Define $B'$ as $\delta B$ where $B$ is the unit ball.

Let $C = (x + B')\cap (y + B')$
Let $M_x$ be the "crescent:" $M_x = (x + B')-(y+B')$
Let $R_x = M_x \cap (x - y + C)$

Somehow it's "easy to see" that for any $z \in M_x - R_x$, $|| z - 2x + y|| \gt \delta$ but I don't see it easily at all. Why is it true?

Here is a diagram with $M_y = (y + B') - (x - B')$ labeled instead of $M_x$ [image]

Diagram and question from this paper: http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/vol5.pdf page 14

Comment: At this point it's not even clear that the diagram is correct. It seems that $R_x$ is made up of two disconnected regions but couldn't it be that $R_x$ is a ball with a small lens shaped hole in it if $C$ is small enough?

Comment: Correction to my above comment: What if $M_x - R_x$ is a ball with a small lens shaped hole in it if $C$ is small enough?

Comment: Hi Mark. If $C$ is small then $M_x-R_x$ is a ball with lenses on both sides removed. The )-shaped arc moves left and the (-shaped arc moves right until they no longer intersect. When this happens it doesn't change the fact that $\left\|z-2x+y\right\|\gt\delta$ because this condition means (in loose terms) that $z$ is to the right of the )-shaped arc. I'm not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: Is it possible for the ) shaped arc to somehow end up interior to the ball $M_x$? Then it would remove a hole instead of the side.

Comment: Which ball? $M_x$ is a crescent.

Comment: Yes sorry, is it possible for $x - y + C$ to end up completely interior of $M_x$? Then it would be a crescent with a hole in it

Comment: Yes, that's possible, though it's not really a hole because $x-y+C$ and $M_x$ have a common boundary on their left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper has $z\in M_x\setminus R_x$, not $z\in R_x$ so maybe that's confusing you.

Also, I think the diagram is right. Region $M_y$ is labelled correctly; $M_x$ is its mirror image on the left side (the crescent containing $R_x$).

To your main question: $M_x\setminus R_x$ is the two "triangular" regions at the north and south poles of $x+B^{'}$. So

\begin{eqnarray*}
M_x\setminus R_x &=& [(x+B^{'})-(y+B^{'})] \setminus (x-y+C) \\
&=& [(x+B^{'})-(y+B^{'})] \setminus (x-y+[(x+B^{'})\cap (y+B^{'})]) \\
&=& [(x+B^{'})-(y+B^{'})] \setminus [(2x-y+B^{'})\cap (x+B^{'})].
\end{eqnarray*}

$\left\| z-2x+y \right\|\gt \delta$ is implied by the "$\setminus [(2x-y+B^{'})$".

Comment: Oh yeah I posed my question incorrectly. Could you address what I asked in my comment? What if the shape isn't two triangular regions? In other words why can we ignore the $(x + B')$ part?